# Postgres - pair elements of one array with elements of another

Tags: postgresql

The values to pair are defined in two arrays, `array[1,2,3]` and `array['A','B','C']`.

What I need to do is merge these two arrays together, where each element is paired with one at the same index in the other, so it results in `array[[1,'A'],[2,'B'],[3,'C']]`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UNNEST WITH ORDINALITY` & join the 2 result this way:

**Schema (PostgreSQL v14)**

```
CREATE TABLE array_zip (
    id INT,
    a1 INT[],
    a2 TEXT[]
);

INSERT INTO array_zip
VALUES (1, ARRAY [1, 2, 3], ARRAY ['A', 'B', 'C'])
     , (2, ARRAY [4, 5, 6], ARRAY ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G']) -- different number of elements
;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT id, zip
FROM array_zip
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT array_agg((aa1.v, aa2.v)) AS zip
    FROM UNNEST(a1) WITH ORDINALITY AS aa1(v, i)
    -- use an INNER JOIN instead to shortcut the zip of the first missing element
    FULL JOIN UNNEST(a2) WITH ORDINALITY AS aa2(v, i)
      USING (i)
) AS f
;
```

| id | zip |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"(1,A)","(2,B)","(3,C)"} |
| 2 | {"(4,D)","(5,E)","(6,F)","(,G)"} |

---

**Query #2**

You could also avoid the `JOIN` between the two arrays with an index-based direct access, which *should* be faster (but probably not by a lot, unless the arrays here are pretty big):

```
SELECT id, zip
FROM array_zip
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT array_agg((a1[i], a2[i])) AS zip
    -- use LEAST instead to stop the zip on the first missing element
    FROM generate_series(1, GREATEST(cardinality(a1), cardinality(a2))) AS i
) AS f;
```

| id | zip |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"(1,A)","(2,B)","(3,C)"} |
| 2 | {"(4,D)","(5,E)","(6,F)","(,G)"} |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cQ4mbUZuHimsagJjxgxAFf/2)

---

The last option I can think of is writing a function (either PL/pgSQL, or PL/v8, or...). The code would probably be easier to understand (especially if you need this feature in multiple queries) and you could handle the `len(arr1) != len(arr2 -> raise` case if you want/need to.